# Hibernate не видит Entity class

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

При связывании с базой данных в Java и использовании `getCriteriaBuilder`

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class
>   DataBase.entity.PlaceTable

При этом определен класс `PlaceTable`:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "place" )
public class PlaceTable {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "idplace" )
    private int placeId;

    @Column( name = "idparking")
    private String parkingId;

    @Column( name = "car" )
    private boolean flagCar;

    @Column( name = "bike" )
    private boolean flagBike;

    @Column( name = "truck" )
    private boolean flagTruck;

    @Column( name = "bus" )
    private boolean flagBus;

    @Column( name = "flag" )
    private boolean empty;

    @Column( name = "idcar" )
    private String carId;

    @Column( name = "timeBegin")
    private int timeBegin;
```

Вот вызов обращения к базе

```
    public ArrayList<PlaceTable> getWithCriteria( String field, String value ) throws HibernateException{

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<PlaceTable> query = builder.createQuery(PlaceTable.class);
        Root<PlaceTable> root = query.from( PlaceTable.class );
        query.select(root).where(builder.equal( root.get( field ), value ) );
        Query<PlaceTable> q = session.createQuery(query);
        return ( ArrayList<PlaceTable> )q.getResultList();
    }
```

Данное исключение выкидывается на строке `Root<PlaceTable> root = query.from( PlaceTable.class );`

Подключение к базе осуществляется посредством методов:

```
private static final String hibernate_show_sql = "true";
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static final String DB_DIALECT  = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
private static final String DB_DRIVER   = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_URL      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false";
private static final String DB_USERNAME = "root";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "geo";


public DBService() {
    Configuration configuration = getMySqlConfiguration();
    sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
private Configuration getMySqlConfiguration() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ParkingTable.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(CarTable.class);

    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",                 DB_DIALECT );
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", DB_DRIVER );
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",          DB_URL );
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",     DB_USERNAME );
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",     DB_PASSWORD );
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",                hibernate_show_sql );
    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: Покажите конфигурацию hibernate

Comment: А где она находится?

Comment: я сам коефигурацию не писал, до этого таких проблем не было, например при обычном получении данных по id

Comment: вы же указываете к какой базе подключаться  и по какому адресу, логин и пароль. скиньте этот файл с настройками

Comment: Это все делаю через метод класса, сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: добавьте configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PlaceTable.class); в последний класс

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что то я не внимателен совсем был, сейчас нужно будет следующие ошибки разбирать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> добавьте configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PlaceTable.class); в последний класс

Спасибо [NetL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190220/netl)